# Service doesn't start after button click in widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

I'm trying to launch service after clicking button in widget but somehow the      service doesn't start. I look all over the internet and didn't found answer for it.

This is onUpdate method

```
 public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        // Create an intent to launch the service
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);

        // PendingIntent is required for the onClickPendingIntent that actually
        // starts the service from a button click
        PendingIntent pendingServiceIntent =
                PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach a click listener to the
        // button
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.meat);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
        Log.i(TAG, "onUpdate is on");
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingServiceIntent);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    }
```

I also tried onRecive method

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent (context, MyService.class);
    intent1.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startService (intent1);
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

I tried test it by toast message

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "the service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This is the onStartCommand

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        timer = new MyCounter(21600000,1000);
        RemoteViews v = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.meat);
        v.setTextViewText(R.id.textView2, getCurrentTime());
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, v);
        timer.start();
        Toast.makeText(context, "the service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, v);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

My manifest

```html
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

       <receiver android:name=".meat" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/meat_info" />
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK_RECEIVER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start a service you have to call [startService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)) method in onReceive. So just replace this line:

```
context.startActivity (intent1);
```

With this:

```
context.startService(intent1);
```

And also be sure to override [onStartCommand](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) method for started service

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried it and it dosen't work. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @user4811620 have you tried adding breakpoints in onUpdate and onReceive methods, just to check if they are called? And also try adding breakpoints in the Service as well. Just to make it clear, the fact that Toasts are not displayed does not mean that your service is not started, Service is not intended to interact with the UI

Comment: I checked in debug mode and onUpdate and onReceive aren't called. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Can you show how do you specify listeners for these callbacks? As for onReceive - I suppose you're using BroadcastReceiver - in this case can you please show me how do you register it and how do you send a broadcast

Comment: I want to do it without using BroadcastReceiver (beacuse I want it to update in interval of 1min). I have already succedd to do it without it but I don't remember how.

Comment: I mean can you post the code of how are you trying to trigger these events. Since they are not called this means that the problem is somewhere there

Comment: What do you mean? its doesn't call the onUpdate when I create the widget for the first time(and when it's updated)? cuase I don't have a configure activity.